# UIButton shows/hide content

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, uibutton

Is it possible that when user clicks on button it shows or hide content. If yes, it is possible animate the transition?

Comment: Please explain which content exactly you want to hide/show.

Answer (score 1):

YES.

You can create a custom button, add inside it a UILable or UIimage  and hide, show  and animate it as you wish.

tell if you need more details.

Comment: Thank you for reply, so I have to make a "box" and hidding content by animation which using alfa settings?

Comment: Hi tomas, first off all it is better that you will add comments instead of answering your own question. it will keep the thread cleaner. is changing the label alpha is all you need?

Comment: What is displayed in the "box". I think the easiest way is to add a subview and animate the change of alpha of that subview after touch on that button.

Comment: Sorry guys I did not know that new here. In the "box" there are another labels and icons. And under the box there is another one, separated by another picture with another button to hide the second box, and I want if user hide the first box, down box slide up for more space.

Comment: @Itamar: Yes, you can leave comments with a rep of 1 when you originally asked the question.

Comment: well, I think i understand what you want but not sure. can you post your code here.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. You will want to use the `tap up inside` action of the UIButton in interface builder.

As for animating it, just wrap the code with

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil]
//code to animate the view
[UIView commitAnimations]
```

As of iOS 4, you can use blocks to animate as well. See this for more reference:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH6-SW3

Comment: The event is actually TouchUpInside.